# CSS Flexbox Responsive Layout and % widths

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

Using [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), I have a simple two-column layout.

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
    <div fxFlex="35%">
        <!-- Left Column -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="65%">
        <!-- Right Column -->
    </div>
</div>
```

On small displays I want the columns to wrap, right below left.

Using angular/flex-layout's [Responsive API](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API), I add a breakpoint for small screens (between 600px and 959px) with `fxLayout.sm="column"` on the container element:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column">
    <div fxFlex="35%">
        <!-- Left Column, Top Row -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="65%">
        <!-- Right Column, Bottom Row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

On small screens the Left Column becomes the Top Row, and Right Column, the Bottom Row.

However, `fxFlex="35%"` and `fxFlex="65%"` attributes are still honored, and so the rows overlap. The Top Row occupies 35% of the display **height**, since it previously occupied 35% of the display **width**.

Please see [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/sXQq67disgCKYOLssuXX/) for an example of the problem. Note, I used the `fxLayout.xs` breakpoint rather than `fxLayout.sm` to demonstrate the problem since Plunker's divides the display up into small sections.

I can fix this by explicitly removing `fxFlex` using the Responsive API (i.e. `fxFlex=""`):

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column">
    <div fxFlex="35%" fxFlex.sm="">
        <!-- Left Column, Top Row -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="65%" fxFlex.sm="">
        <!-- Right Column, Bottom Row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Please [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/PnL2tNXKMvfIpt2TwJ89/) for an example of the solution.

There are two problems with this. Firstly, it feels very, very hacky. Secondly, assuming I want the same behaviour for small and extra small displays, I end up with:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div fxFlex="35%" fxFlex.sm="" fxFlex.xs="">
        <!-- Left Column, Top Row -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="65%" fxFlex.sm="" fxFlex.xs="">
        <!-- Right Column, Bottom Row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Unless there's any easier way to use the Responsive API for displays below a certain dimension, rather than set breakpoints explicitly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The angular-flex-layout Responsive API also has a `gt-sm` (greater than small) property.

To avoid having to add every screen size with an `fxFlex=""` value you can just do something like this:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div fxFlex.gt-sm="35%">
        <!-- Left Column, Top Row -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex.gt-sm="65%">
        <!-- Right Column, Bottom Row -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use the `lt-lg` (less than large) property and have

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayout.sm="column" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div fxFlex="35%" fxFlex.lt-lg="">
        <!-- Left Column, Top Row -->
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="65%"  fxFlex.lt-lg="">
        <!-- Right Column, Bottom Row -->
    </div>
</div>
```